# Representing Groups as matrices

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

How to represent any group as group of matrices ?
Like how to represent dihedral (4) group (order $8$) as group of $2$ by $2$ matrices ?
How to represent direct product of $Z_2$ and $Z_2$ as a group of $4$ by $4$ matrices ?
similarly with quaternion group.
Is there any general procedure ?

Comment: Any subgroup of $S_n$ can be represented using permutation matrices, and in this fashion you can get a representation for any finite group.  However, this will not generally give you an irreducible representation.

Answer (score 4):

Any finite group $G$ can be represented as a group of matrices in the following way. First, realize $G$ as a subgroup of a permutation group acting on $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ (this is possible by Cayley's theorem).

Then each $g \in G$ permutes the set $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, and we can define a map $G \to M_{n}(\mathbb R)$ from $G$ to the set of $n \times n$-matrices over $\mathbb {R}$: the permutation $g$ is sent to the matrix with columns $e_{g(i)}$, where $e_i$ are the basis vectors.

One can check that this is actually a group homomorphism.

**EXAMPLE** Let $G=\mathbb Z_4$. Then $G$ can be realized as the permutation subgroup generated by the permutation $(1234)$. So we send $1 \in \mathbb Z_4$ to the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$
And so on.

This is by no means the most "efficient" way of embedding $G$ in $GL_k$ (the group of invertible matrices). To do this efficiently, is one of the things representation theory deals with.

Comment: so in $Z_2$ x $Z_2$ I need to map generators to a matrix ? how am I supposed to do so ?

Comment: @user119065 Well, $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ can be represented as the group generated by the two permutations $(12)$ and $(34)$. Then you do the same as I did in the $\mathbb Z_4$-example

Comment: so in youre example, I can map 2 to a matrix which is permutation of the rows ?

Comment: @user119065 Yes, since $2$ corresponds to the permutation $(13)(24)$, you just cycle the columns one more time. But this is not necessary. You just multiply the matrix with itelf.